# Android app installs new instead of updating

Tags: android

I recently created an update of my android app but when happens when i run or install it, it installs a fresh copy of the app instead of updating it. The first app whose designed using eclipse, the update was created using Android studio. Kindly help me identify what is causing this.

Comment: Are both their package names same?

Comment: Did you handle the version code correctly ? If both are version 1.0 it will not update... The update has to be higher : for a minor 1.1 or a major 2.0

Comment: Do you even need the old version? Certainly Android Studio will update the correct one from now on and you can uninstall the old one

Answer (score 1):

You certainly changed the application Id of your application.

Check the old `AndroidManifest.xml` file and compare package with the application Id on your new `app/build.gradle` file.

[image: AndroidManifest.xml]
 [image: app/build.gradle]

Hope that it helps.

Best regards.